# error while copy list to matrix python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix

i have a list with 12 elements like

```
list_ = [1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 6 ,7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

i'd like to copy its values to a 3 x 4 matrix, i did the follow:

```
matrix = [[0] * 4 ] * 3

list_index = 0
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(4):
        matrix[i][j] = list_[list_index]
        list_index += 1
```

But i had a bad result, i repeat only the last ligne, when i print:

```
print(matrix)
```

the result is:

> [[9, 10, 11, 12], [9, 10, 11, 12], [9, 10, 11, 12]]

Comment: You should add the [tag:python] tag for better coverage (more people can see your question)

Comment: Try: `[data[i:i+4] for i in range(0, 12, 4)]`

Comment: id resolve it with:
for i in range(3):
 matrix.append([])
 for j in range(4):
  matrix[i].append(list_[list_index])
  list_index += 1